# DGEMM and Numerical Constants as Arguments

Tags: fortran, lapack, intel-fortran, intel-mkl

While using BLAS [DGEMM](http://www.netlib.org/blas/dgemm.f) matrix-multiply function, I noticed that for an uninitialized result matrix C, I get NaNs in the resultwhen I call it like so:

```
DGEMM('N', 'N', M, N, K, 1.0, A, LDA, B, LDB, 0.0, C, LDC)
```

However, if I declare ALPHA and BETA before-hand:

```
REAL*8 ALPHA, BETA
PARAMETER (ALPHA=1.0)
PARAMETER (BETA=0.0)

DGEMM('N', 'N', M, N, K, ALPHA, A, LDA, B, LDB, BETA, C, LDC)
```

then the multiplication works okay. Does anyone have any ideas as to why declaring the arguments works?

Note that I'm using the Intel Fortran compiler along with it's MKL library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would work if you passed `alpha` and `beta` as *double precision* numerical constants (eg, `1.d0`), but you're passing it single precision constants, and Fortran 77 has no way of knowing dgemm's argument list and promoting the reals to double precision.   (It might work with the single precision constants if you used MKL's Fortran 95 interface, but I'm not sure).

Because you're only passing pointers 4-byte arguments and the library subroutine is looking up 8-byte values, the rest of the calculation gets messed up.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was passing the wrong type. Yeah, it's strange that I didn't get any runtime errors. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to get compile-time errors, use an explicit interface. Use the MKL or Lapack90 module (better) or define an interface block by hand (worse).

Comment: As Fortran arguments are passed by address, there is no way that an argument of the wrong kind would mess up all the arguments that come after it. A runtime error would only occur if the single precision argument happened to lie in the last 4 bytes of a memory page right before an unallocated memory region - quite a rare event.